# how to fill cells by column first?

Tags: matlab, sorting, for-loop

How would you fill columns first with a defined variable, then move down and fill by column first?

For instance, I have an array filled with 24 names (24x1) and I want to split the names into 4 groups (columns). I want 4 names in each column till the 24th name.

Comment: We need more details about how your names are stored. E.g., maybe you can get by with a simple reshape(my_array,6,4) but we can't be sure until we know more.

Comment: Do you want "4 groups (columns)", or do you want "4 names in each column"? Please post a [mre].

Comment: @James Tursa four columns - I figured it out though by transposing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it

1.Transpose your matrix at the end:

```
example=example.'
```

or

```
example=transpose(example)
```

2.You can directly fill in column:

I write an example down there. The important part is `a(it,1)=it`

```
it=1;
while it~=25
    a(it,1)= it;
    it=it+1;
end
```